# Transposing a Column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have requirement in which I have to return data in following format:

```
Batch Id  Element1  Element2 Element3  .. Element n  Date
------------------------------------------------------------
1        0.25      1.5      3.5           2.2        1/12/2014
2        1.3       2.3      5.5           1.1        5/12/2014
3        4.5       5.5      4.3           6.3        7/12/2014
..        ..       ..       ..            ..         ..
n        1.5       2.3      5.5           9.3       12/12/2014
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

where I have two tables in which data is stored in following format:
Table1:

```
Batch Id  CreatedBy   Date
-----------------------------------------------
1         ABC         1/12/2014
2         PQR         5/12/2014
3         XYZ         7/12/2014
..        ..          ..
n         YYY         12/12/2014
----------------------------------------------
```

Table2:

```
Batch Id  Element           Value
-----------------------------------------------
1         Element1          0.25
1         Element2          1.5
1         Element3          3.5
..        ..                ..
1         Elementn          2.2

2         Element1          1.3
2         Element2          2.3
2         Element3          5.5
..        ..                ..
2         Elementn          6.3

.         .                 .
.         .                 .
.         .                 .
n         Element1          1.5
n         Element2          2.3
n         Element3          5.5
..        ..                ..
n         Elementn          9.3
----------------------------------------------
```

My Question is How can I Transpose records in Table2 [i.e. Element and its Value] to display my result in required format? Please note, The number of elements in each Batch is not same.But I have the list of maximum elements that can appear.

Any Suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Best Regards,
Kunal

Comment: Oracle 11G has PIVOT clause for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach to Solution Using Pivoting Operation**

1. construct a query where tables are joined (assumed inner join) with necessary columns: batch_id, batch_date, element, value
2. assume one element value per batch (thus summing is an effective function).  The key is that this needs to be an aggregation function.
3. add the pivot clause using the syntax here, [Oracle 11g Pivoting Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG8729).
4. the for section of the pivot clause enables you to segment the aggregation/create the new element columns.

`SELECT batch_id,
  element1,
  element2,
  --assume finite list
  elementn,
  batch_date
FROM
  (SELECT batch.batch_id,
    batch.DATE batch_date,
    batch_element.element b_element,
    batch_element.value b_value
  FROM table1 batch
  JOIN table2 batch_element
  ON batch.batch_id = batch_element.batch_id
    --assume want to see only batches with elements
  ) pivot (sum(b_value) FOR b_element IN (('Element1') AS element1, ('Element2') AS element2, ('Element3') AS element3, ('Element4') AS element4, ...
  --assume finite list as indicated
  ('ElementN') AS elementn ));`

Here is an example using the sample scott schema where average salaries are calculated by job:

```
SCOTT@dev> SELECT job,
  2    accounting,
  3    research,
  4    sales
  5  FROM
  6    (SELECT d.dname,
  7      e.job,
  8      e.sal
  9    FROM dept d
 10    LEFT JOIN emp e
 11    ON d.deptno                  = e.deptno
 12    ) pivot (avg(sal) FOR dname IN ('ACCOUNTING' AS accounting, 'RESEARCH' AS research, 'SALES' AS sales))
 13  /

JOB       ACCOUNTING   RESEARCH      SALES
========= ========== ========== ==========

CLERK           1300        950        950
SALESMAN                              1400
PRESIDENT       5000
MANAGER         2450       2975       2850
ANALYST                    3000

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Hello Patrick, this was really helpful, especially your comments above helped me to understand its working,Thanks!